# ¿Cómo hacer UPDATE de en una columna de tabla Mysql con una Sub-Query que contiene una parte fija?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
|  ID |                 url                   |
|-----|---------------------------------------|
|  1  |  item/ldksfnsldknfsdfioj34j30h34i034  | 
|  2  |  item/09d0s8ysd8c0dsjc89shd7csd9chs9  |
| ... |  ...                                  |
```

Quiero aplicar un nuevo método de general la cadena aleatoria de caracteres, que es:

```
SELECT LEFT(UUID(), 28);
```

Pero no sé cómo escribir la query para que me haga un UPDATE en toda la columna `url` a la vez. Me imagino que deberia ser algo como:

```
UPDATE tabla
   SET url = ('items/' (SELECT LEFT(UUID(), 28));
```

Pero me sale error:

> syntax to use near '(SELECT LEFT(UUID(), 28))' at line 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se debe a que estas concantenando las cadenas `'items/'` y `LEFT(UUID(), 28)`.

### Solución:

Podrías usar [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) para concatenar las cadenas, así:

```
UPDATE tabla
  SET url = CONCAT('items/', LEFT(UUID(), 28))
```